# OpenCV: How to Efficiently Multiply Each Element of a Mat2d matrix by a Mat1d matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have a Mat2d matrix, where each element is a 2D vector. For example:

```
[[x0, y0], [x1, y1]
 [x2, y2], [x3, y3]]
```

I want to left multiply each of these vectors by a Mat1d camera matrix:

```
[fx, 0,  cx, 
 0,  fy, cy, 
 0,  0,  1]
```

(Each vector represents the location of a vertex in a grid which I want to convert from the camera space to the pixel space.)

The resulting matrix, for this example, would be:

```
[[x0 * fx + cx, y0 * fy + cy], [x1 * fx + cx, y1 * fy + cy]
 [x2 * fx + cx, y2 * fy + cy], [x3 * fx + cx, y3 * fy + cy]]
```

What is the most straightforward and efficient way to accomplish this?

---

Here is my current approach:

```cpp
Mat2d points = getMesh();
Mat1d cameraMtrx = getCameraMtrx();

for(int col = 0; col < points.cols; col++){
    for(int row = 0; row < points.rows; row++){
        points.at<Vec2d>(row, col).val[0] = points.at<Vec2d>(row, col)[0] * cameraMtrx.at<double>(0, 0) + cameraMtrx.at<double>(0, 2);
        points.at<Vec2d>(row, col).val[1] = points.at<Vec2d>(row, col)[1] * cameraMtrx.at<double>(1, 1) + cameraMtrx.at<double>(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: should be nearly the fastest way, you could extract (introduce cariables) fx fy cx and cy from the mat and reduce function calls that way. And you could use row-pointers for the points, which is a little bit more efficient than .at function

Comment: NO, you are iterating over cols in outer and rows in inner loop. Do it the other way around and it will be much more efficient! (row major order!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV [Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html) has already detailed various methods of iterating the `cv::Mat` efficiently, Out of the presented methods, the most efficient way is to use `cv::LUT()`, but from the context of this question, I guess the range of input matrix values is not fixed, so a look-up table can't be created, It is very helpful in case of `RGB` images, because we  know beforehand that min value would be `0` and max value would be `255`, so we can easily create a lookUp table, but in this problem, we need to multiply two matrices which I assume are not images so we would go with [The efficient way](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way).

```
int cameraMatrix[] = {2, 0, 10, 0, 4, 20, 0, 0, 1};
cv::Mat mat(2, 2, CV_32FC2, cv::Scalar(100, 20));
cv::Size contSize = mat.size();

// Calculate the length of array if the input matrix was flatten, in case of continuous matrix only.
if (mat.isContinuous()) {
    contSize.width *= contSize.height;
    contSize.height = 1;
}

cv::Vec2f* ptr;
for (int i = 0; i < contSize.height; ++i)
{
    ptr = mat.ptr<cv::Vec2f>(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < contSize.width; ++j)
    {
        ptr[j] = cv::Vec2f(ptr[j].val[0]*cameraMatrix[0] + cameraMatrix[2], ptr[j].val[1] * cameraMatrix[4] + cameraMatrix[5]);
    }
}
```